# java reading back printed file with empty first line

Tags: java, file-io

I have a piece of code printing newlines in a file, like this:

```
if(reply3.equals("")){
pc2.println("");
}
```

Then some string of NNNNNNNNNN's is printed on separate lines. I have difficulty reading back this file using a scanner dur. This is because the printed file starts with an empty line.

```
dur.nextLine();
dur.nextLine();
 for(int r = 0; r < internalc2line; r++){
  dur.nextLine();
 }
```

There are several possible solutions:
How can I instruct the program so that it does not start printing an empty line?
How can I delete the first empty line from the file?
How can I start reading back the file from the second line (I tried this by calling dur.nextLine() twice but it gives a noSuchElementException)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should take into account that you read two lines. thus your counter `r` should start from 2 not 0.
Instead of `.equals("")` you can use `isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

`BufferedReader br = new FileReader(new File(X));`

`String s;`

`while((s=br.nextLine())== " ")
{br.nextLine();}`

just make it read the empty lines and let the GC take care of the objects. 
note i haven't tested this in anyway

Comment: this will not work as an exception will be thrown if there is no nextline